# Emacs mail - The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: email, gnutls, smtpmail

I am trying to send mail through emacs via my gmail account. I understand that this means it is senting using SMTP.

However, when I go through the basic steps to send mail through my gmail account,

```
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

I am following the information found [here](http://tonyballantyne.com/tech/sending-email-from-emacs/) which seems very easy, however I get that error.

At first I got a warning from google about a suspicious sign in attempt, but I have enabled that and now get this strange TLS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Below are my settings for sending mail through GMail:

```lisp
(require 'nnir)

(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "gmail"
               (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
               (nnimap-server-port 993)
               (nnimap-stream ssl)
               (nnir-search-engine imap)))

(setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials
      '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
      smtpmail-auth-credentials
      (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo")
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      smtpmail-debug-info t)
(require 'smtpmail)
```

I think that GMail listens on port 587 rather than 25, that's why there's a connection error.  But that's just a guess.